# Get content of page type in Kentico10 via Rest service

Tags: kentico

I am trying to retrieve data of page type via rest service in Kentico 10.
What should be format of base URL for sending Post request and for checking content on browser?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to retrieve content you have to use `GET` (not `POST`). `POST` is for [creating resources](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/integrating-3rd-party-systems/kentico-rest-service/manipulating-data-using-rest/managing-pages-using-rest#ManagingpagesusingREST-Creatingpages), `PUT` is for [updating](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/integrating-3rd-party-systems/kentico-rest-service/manipulating-data-using-rest/managing-pages-using-rest#ManagingpagesusingREST-Updatingexistingpages).

From the documentation:

> The base URL of the Kentico REST service is /rest.
>   For example, if your site is running at http://localhost/Kentico, use
>   http://localhost/Kentico/rest as the base URL of the service.

This is how you retrieve all documents with all their coupled data:

[`http://localhost/Kentico/rest/content/currentsite/en-us/all/?coupleddata=true`](http://localhost/Kentico/rest/content/currentsite/en-us/all/?coupleddata=true)

Again, see the [documentation](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/integrating-3rd-party-systems/kentico-rest-service/getting-data-using-rest#GettingdatausingREST-Gettingpagedata) for all the examples.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
/content/currentsite/<culture>/all/?classnames=<class code name>
```

[Here](https://docs.kentico.com/k9/integrating-3rd-party-systems/kentico-rest-service/getting-data-using-rest) you can find all the details on getting content/data via Kentico rest service.